# What is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that the function $f(t)=(t-0.5)^2$ over the interval [0,1] is measurable on?

Tags: measure-theory

> What is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that the function
>   $f(t)=(t-0.5)^2$ over the interval $[0,1]$ is measurable on?

So, I'm fairly new to this subject, I think that the smallest one would be $\{{ \phi, [0,0.25] }\}$ since by definition, sigma fields have to include the empty set and the range of the image, sounds a bit too simple though..

Any help?

Comment: Let $g:t\mapsto1-t$. For every Borel subset $B$ of $[0,.5]$, one needs $B\cup g(B)$ in the sigma-algebra, and in fact the sigma-algebra is exactly made of these.

Comment: so just to clarify, that would mean the $\sigma $ algebra  is $[0,0.5] \cup [0.5,1]=[0,1]$?

Comment: No. Do you have the slightest idea of what the words "sigma-algebra" mean?

Comment: I read some now and I think I do, but the combination of measurable functions and sigma-algebras is new and confusing to me